# Multiple columns horizontally - Group By month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have some SQL which returns the following information:

| Date | Month | Balance | Transactions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | January | 20 | Test 1 |
| 02/01/2020 | January | 21 | Test 2 |
| 01/02/2020 | February | 20 | Test 3 |
| 02/02/2020 | February | 21 | Test 4 |

I'd like to get the information so it's like this:

| Date | January | Balance | Transactions | Date | February | Balance | Transactions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | January | 20 | Test 1 | 01/02/2020 | February | 20 | Test 3 |
| 02/01/2020 | January | 21 | Test 2 | 02/02/2020 | February | 21 | Test 4 |

Any ideas? I've tried Pivots, and it's close, but not there.

Thank in advance for your help!

Comment: *it's close, but not there.* - please, show us how close it is with your code. Pivot should not be *close*: it does the thing or not (based on such simple requirement of fixed number and name of columns).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use conditional aggregation along with `row_number()`:

```
select max(case when month = 'January' then date end),
       'January',
       max(case when month = 'January' then balance end),
       max(case when month = 'January' then transactions end),
       max(case when month = 'February' then date end),
       'February',
       max(case when month = 'February' then balance end),
       max(case when month = 'February' then transactions end)           
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by month order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```